# Difference between ElasticNet in scikit-learn Python and Glmnet in R

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, glmnet, elastic-net

Has anybody tried to verify whether fitting an Elastic Net model with `ElasticNet` in scikit-learn in Python and `glmnet` in R on the same data set produces identical arithmetic results? I have been experimenting with many combinations of the parameters ( since the two functions differ in the default values they pass to the arguments) and also scaling the data, but nothing seems to produce the same model between the two languages. Has anybody faced the same issue?

Comment: https://github.com/bbalasub1/glmnet_python

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally I got the same values with the following code :

Python

```
# normalize function that gives the same with R
def mystandardize(D):
   S = np.std(D, axis=0, ddof=1)
   M = np.mean(D, axis = 0)
   D_norm = (D-M)/S
return [D_norm, M, S]

Y_norm_train = pd.DataFrame(mystandardize(Y_train)[0])
glmnet_regr = linear_model.ElasticNet(alpha=1, l1_ratio = 0.01,
                                  fit_intercept = True, normalize =    False, tol=0.0000001, max_iter = 100000)
glmnet_regr.fit(X_train, Y_norm_train)
```

R

```
y_norm_train <- scale(y[train_idx])
glmnet_obj_norm <- glmnet(x_train, y_norm_train, alpha=0.01, lambda = 1,  
                   thresh = 1e-07, standardize = FALSE, intercept=TRUE, standardize.response = FALSE)
print_coef(glmnet_obj_norm)
```

Comment: There is a relatively new python wrapper for the Fortran code used in the *R* package `glmnet`. This should also get you the same results as in *R*.  
https://github.com/civisanalytics/python-glmnet

Comment: It is still strange that the results differ for non-standardized data. There's not reason that they should as far as I know.